# How to change colour of the thumb in seekbar?

Tags: android, xml, seekbar

I have the default `seekbar` in my android app. I noticed that when the `thumb` on the `seekbar` is held, it turns yellow. Instead, I want it to turn blue when it is held. How can this be done? I apologize if this is a basic question, I am new to android development. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't like the default thumb, you will have to create your own [`Drawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html), which you can then set the thumb in code with something like:

```java
Drawable thumb = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.myThumb );
SeekBar mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySeekBar);
mSeekbar.setThumb(thumb);
```

Or you can set the thumb in XML with:

```
<SeekBar 
    ...
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb" />
```

The actual Drawable can be an image, shape, or any other kind of Drawable you could possibly desire. If you want the thumb to change appearance when it is pressed, you will want to create a [`State List Drawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Comment: I want to use the default thumb. I just want to change the color it changes to when held.

Comment: Unfortunately the pressed color of the default thumb is a part of the default thumb itself. If you want to change it, you need to implement it yourself. I found the the [non-holo default images here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res), so you should be able to use those to get a good start.

Comment: This is a useful technique for some situations, but it's not necessarily true that you *have* to create your own Drawable. See @zavidovych's answer, for API 16+.

Answer (score 33):

Use image filters to change color of default State List Drawables (including SeekBar):

```
  // Change seekbar color to green.
  SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
  sb.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
  sb.getThumb().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

The method `getThumb` is only available since API 16+ (Jelly Bean).

Comment: Found it better in my case to use `sb.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);`

Comment: @CrimsonX you should add this as a answer.

Comment: Or you can use `android:progressTint="@color/yourColor"` in xml file

Comment: `setColorFilter(int color, @NonNull Mode mode)` is deprecated

Answer (score 24):

No need of additional styling. Android supports it via xml.
Just add **android:thumbTint="@color/yourColor"** in your seekbar.

For eg.

```
<SeekBar
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:max="100"
     android:thumbTint="@color/red"
     android:progress="0" />
```

Comment: What about for api < 21?

Comment: @JohnShelley This works for all API levels using AppCompat theme...

In styles.xml:

`<style name="AppTheme.BlueSeekBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
    </style>`

In layout:
`<SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.BlueSeekBar"  />`

Comment: @Breeno this works, but only for the thumb (on old APIs). How would you style the rest of the seekbar?

Comment: You can use `DrawableCompat.setTint` to add tint in support versions