# Customizing the android seekbar thumb

Tags: android, drawable, seekbar

I want to 1) change the color of the thumb to a color int I have in my code. and 2) make sure there is no whitespace between the progress and the thumb

```
Drawable thumb = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thumb, getContext().getTheme());
// seekbarColorStr can be #0011FF, etc
thumb.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(seekbarColorStr), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
seekBar.setThumb(thumb);
```

My thumb.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">

<size
    android:height="20dp"
    android:width="20dp" />

</shape>
```

I got the idea for changing the color in [How to change colour of the thumb in seekbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470475/how-to-change-colour-of-the-thumb-in-seekbar)

The thumb renders black, and since it is circular while the progress is rectangular, there is whitespace between the two.

Comment: Try setting [`seekBar.setSplitTrack(false);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.html#setSplitTrack(boolean)).

Comment: @EugenPechanec thanks, but that only exists in API 21 and up.  What about pre Lollipop?

Answer (score 0):

the proper PorterDuff mode is SRC_IN, not Multiply in order to render the color.