# What is the name of this element that appears under the carriage?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In order to customize my app, I'm changing color scheme. I was able to change the cursor color, but I don't know how is this thing called, let alone changing it's color.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470475/how-to-change-colour-of-the-thumb-in-seekbar)? Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis "android edittext thumb" doesn't return anything relevant