# Android Seekbar set progress by user input

Tags: android, seekbar

I want the seekbar progress to work with user input like the range is between 1-100 and if I enter 50 the thumb should come in middle. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

## ColorSlider.java

```
public class ColorSlider extends AppCompatActivity {

private SeekBar seekBar = null;
private View view;
private TextView progress;
private ShapeDrawable shape;
private EditText userInput;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_slider);

    seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    progress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.progress);
    userInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);

    LinearGradient test = new LinearGradient(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, 320.f, new int[] { 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFFFF0000},
            null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    shape = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    shape.getPaint().setShader(test);

    seekBar.setProgressDrawable((Drawable) shape);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

            progress.setText(" "+i);

        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });


}
```

[image: User Input]

### activity_color_slider.xml

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
    android:splitTrack="false"
    android:thumb="@drawable/drag_thumb"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `TextWatcher` to `Edittext` and set The progress accordingly .

```
 et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String text = editable.toString();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)){
                seekBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(text));
            }
        }
    });
```

Make sure `Edittext` should have `inputType` as `number` . Add `android:inputType="number` to `Edittext`.
**NOTE**:- This will set progress leniently(ex: 50->50%,  10->10%). If you want to show progress with some unit like number 10-> 1% then you need to calculate it inside `afterTextChanged()`

Comment: Sir can I ask you for a little more help ? I am really impressed with your result in such time-oriented way.

Comment: I need to change the thumb color exactly on the color where the value is entered. Is it possible ? Thanks

Comment: I mean if the thumb on entering 50 comes at middle, the middle color is green accordingly can the thumb color get changed according to the given input

Comment: Well you can change thumb color at runtime . But this you will have to do according to progress.Check for progress range inside `aftertextChange()` and set the thumb color accordingly . [Here is a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470475/how-to-change-colour-of-the-thumb-in-seekbar) .

Comment: Thankyou Sir, Really Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

And implement textwatcher for Edittext

```
  youredittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
               seekbar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int aft )                                                                          
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {

    }
});
```